# The exported docx file not getting imported

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, npm

I am using a Meteor package with name "babrahams:html2docx" for creating .docx files on the client from html.
I want to import the same exported file, when I exported and saved the docx file using this package, after that I was unable to import the same file again.
I am using a mammoth package to import the same file.
If I do Save As to same file and save it with different name then the newly saved file gets imported successfully.
also checked online for the type of the file which was exported using package which shows the extension as html.

package syntax to convert the given html data into docx file format.

```
'htmlContent' : function() {
    console.log("import........", Session.get('htmlConvertedData'));
    if (Session.get('htmlConvertedData')) {
        return Session.get('htmlConvertedData');
    }
},
```

code that i have written to define the functionality inside a data-action.

```
var curDataId = new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID($(this).attr('id'));
var document = collname.findOne(curDataId);
var data = exportDataFunction(document); // here the function with name exportDataFunction which returns me the html converted data.
Session.set('htmlConvertedData', data);
```

package syntax to convert the given html data into docx file format.

```
<div class="row headspace">
    <div id="target-element"><span>{{{htmlContent}}}</span></div>
    {{> html2docx selector="#target-element" filename="campaign" linkText="Download Campaign" linkClass="btn"                               includeStylesheets=false useDocNotDocx=false}}
</div>
</div >
```